# How do I use the word "Concordant" in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I was looking for an alternative to "unanimous" and found the word "concordant" in the thesaurus. What would be the best way to use this word?

For example, in an essay, it would be okay to say *"The texts had unanimously agreed on how..."*. Would the same meaning be produced with  "concordant", as in "*The texts had been concordant on how...*"

Could any examples of the word be listed below?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"The texts were concordant on the proper use of quotation marks."

"The movie's opening-weekend gross was fairly concordant with box-office returns for that genre." (example from [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concordant))

I would say "unanimous" means perfect, universal agreement, while "concordant" means general compatibility of opinion or ideas with perhaps some differences on specifics. Better synonyms for concordant would be "harmonious" or "nonconflicting."

Answer (score 2):

> the texts had been concordant on how _".

Er, probably something like

> the texts concorded on how ...

would be more natural.

It's difficult to use the past perfect without any context.

> The texts had concorded on how to make the perfect omelette, yet Sarah discovered that despite all their advice, she could indeed make an omelette without breaking eggs.

Comment: I couldn't find any dictionary entry for 'concord' as a verb, so I'm not too sure if it's right to say "had concorded" or "concorded"

Comment: @Manjima: if you google for "concord meaning" you can find a lot of online dictionaries with a definition.

Comment: @Shinto: I do understand the use of 'concord' as a noun. What I meant was that I couldn't find the verb 'concord' in any dictionaries online.

Comment: http://thinkexist.com/dictionary/meaning/concord/

Comment: Do you really find the verb **concorded** "natural"?